# Flask-Ap Scheduler on Linode Server

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler, linode

I have a `Flask AP scheduler` on my website. The function that I am trying to execute just fine, because I can manually run it from the `Admin page`. When I run the website on the `local server`, the `AP Scheduler` executes correctly. However, on the `linode` server, it will not call the function. Please help! Where is the disconnect!

Thank you!

Below is my schedule.py file. I import that into the **__init.py file where the app is started.**

```
from .python_files.administration import *
from flask_apscheduler.scheduler import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

@scheduler.scheduled_job(trigger="cron",id="NBAUpdate",day_of_week="*",hour=23,minute=15)
def nba_full_update():
    sport = "NBA"
    Admin().full_update(sport)

@scheduler.scheduled_job(trigger="cron",id="NHLUpdate",day_of_week="*",hour=23,minute=16)
def nhl_full_update():
    sport = "NHL"
    Admin().full_update(sport)

@scheduler.scheduled_job(trigger="cron",id="NFLUpdate",day_of_week="*",hour=23,minute=17)
def nfl_full_update():
    sport = "NFL"
    Admin().full_update(sport)

if not scheduler.running:
    scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: some servers may kill process when it runs too long - because it can block access to server for other users. If server gives direct access to `cron` then you could use directly `cron`.

Comment: usually servers send error messages to `log` file - you should check if  `linode` has something in `log`

Comment: do you mean `__init__.py`  or `__init.py`?